# Create Tabs Dynamically Based on Values Selected in Listbox in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, tabs, listbox

does anyone know how can I create tabs **dynamically** based on what is selected from a Listbox?

This is what I have:

**ListBox:**

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="SelectionListBox" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="130px" Width="350px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value ="1"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Watermelon" Value ="2"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Kiwi" Value ="3"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plum" Value ="4"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value ="5"  />
</asp:ListBox>
```

**RetrieveButton:**

```
<asp:Button ID="RetrieveButton" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Based on what the user has selected from the Listbox, when the user pressed on the Retrieve button, number of tabs will be created based on the number of values user has selected from Listbox.

For example:

Let's say user has selected **3 items** from the Listbox and click on the button, **3 tabs** should be created at the bottom of the page on the **same** page with the tab names as the listbox items texts.

**Output:**

+----------------------------------+

```
          ListBox

       RetrieveButton
```

+----------------------------------+

```
           Tabs:

Apple | Watermelon | Kiwi
```

+----------------------------------+

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would depend on how you plan to display the tabs. Using jqueryUI dynamic tabs can easily be added by adding li elements. Refer the code example below (I've used html select - you may have to use the corresponding client id of the listbox)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $("div#tabs").tabs().hide();
  $("button#RetrieveButton").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#SelectionListBox option:selected').each(function () {
          var txt = $(this).text();

          $("div#tabs ul").append(
              "<li><a href='#tab" + txt + "'>#" + txt + "</a></li>");
          $("div#tabs").append(
              "<div id='tab" + txt + "'>#" + txt + "</div>");
          $("div#tabs").tabs("refresh");
      });

      if ($("div#tabs ul li").length) {
          $('div#tabs').show();
          $('button#RetrieveButton').prop('disabled', true);
      }

  });
};
```

Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/hes48o8t/1/)

---

**Edit**: The following code attempts to do the same thing using JavaScript. Please note that the following code is more or less untested, and is an attempt to "reinvent the wheel". Would recommend to use jQueryUI or bootstrap tabs.

**aspx**

```
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .Initial
        {
            display: block;
            padding: 4px 18px 4px 18px;
            float: left;
            /*background: url("../Images/InitialImage.png") no-repeat right top;*/
            background-color: dimgray;
            color: Black;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .Initial:hover
        {
            color: White;
            /*background: url("../Images/SelectedButton.png") no-repeat right top;*/
            background-color: gray;
        }
        .Clicked
        {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            /*background: url("../Images/SelectedButton.png") no-repeat right top;*/
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 4px 18px 4px 18px;
            color: Black;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: White;
        }
        #tabs-content
        {
            float:left;
            clear:both;
        }
        #tabs-content div
        {
            display:none;
            border-style:double;
            border-width:2px;
            min-width: 600px;
            min-height:200px;
        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
       function changeTab(ctrl) {
            var id = ctrl.getAttribute('data-tab');
            var allTabContents = document.getElementById('tabs-content').getElementsByTagName('div');
            var tabContent = document.getElementById(id);

            for (var i = 0; i < allTabContents.length; i++) {
                allTabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            tabContent.style.display = 'block';
        }

        function addTabs() {
            var top = document.getElementById('tabs-link');
            var bottom = document.getElementById('tabs-content');

            var allTabContents = document.getElementById('tabs-content').getElementsByTagName('div');
            var tabCount = 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < allTabContents.length; i++) {
                tabCount++;
            }

            var listBox = document.getElementById('SelectionListBox');
            for (var i = 0; i < listBox.options.length; i++) {
                if (listBox.options[i].selected) {
                    var newTab = document.createElement('div');
                    newTab.setAttribute('class', 'Initial');
                    newTab.setAttribute('data-tab', 'tab'+tabCount);
                    newTab.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeTab(this)');
                    newTab.innerText = listBox.options[i].text;
                    top.appendChild(newTab);

                    var newTabContent = document.createElement('div');
                    newTabContent.setAttribute('id', 'tab' + tabCount);
                    newTabContent.innerText = listBox.options[i].text;
                    bottom.appendChild(newTabContent);

                    tabCount++;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

</script>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListBox ID="SelectionListBox" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="130px" Width="350px">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value ="1"  />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Watermelon" Value ="2"  />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Kiwi" Value ="3"  />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Plum" Value ="4"  />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Pineapple" Value ="5"  />
        </asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="RetrieveButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return addTabs()" />
        <div id="tabs">
            <div id="tabs-link">

            </div>
            <div id="tabs-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Taleeb, thanks for the solution! I am new to jquery so when I tried to add in this piece of code into my project, error occurred. Do you know any other solution other than jquery?

Comment: Are you using any plugin for tabs (basically how do you plan to render the tabs). Also let us know the error you got and we can try to fix that.

Comment: @FeliciaSoh. I've added a code using pure JavaScript (no jQuery/jQueryUI). Among other problems - one problem with the code is that it is not responsive. It would be far better if you can use jQuery or bootstrap for the tabs..

Comment: Hi Taleeb, thanks a lot for all your solutions! You are great! I managed to solve this problem. :)